# check docker-compose up is up and db has started

Tags: mysql, docker

I have this bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash

docker-compose up -d

# wait for the database to come up
until mysqlshow --user=root  -h localhost -P 3306 --protocol=tcp > /dev/null 2>&1; do
    echo "Waiting for mysql container..."
    sleep 0.5
done

RESULT=`mysqlshow --user=root  -h localhost -P 3306 --protocol=tcp payments| grep -o payments`

if ! [[ $RESULT = *"payments"* ]]; then
  ./node_modules/.bin/sequelize db:create
fi

./node_modules/.bin/sequelize db:migrate

yarn start
```

The above does work but it requires `mysql` to be installed locally which sort of defeats the purpose of using docker.

Is there a better way:

1. I can check the db is up without using mysql.
2. I can run a create script perhaps in the container when it starts to create the db if it does not exist.

Answer (score 0):

There is no shame in having tools installed on your host.  These have the advantage of using your local native filesystem without weird remapping tricks and not requiring root privilege to run.  Your script is fine as it is; it does not defeat the purpose of Docker at all.

One "more Dockery" approach you can take to this, particularly if you *always* want to run the migrations, is to move the last half of this into an ENTRYPOINT script in your application container.  I might write a script like:

```
#!/bin/sh
if [ -n "$MYSQL_HOST" -a -z "$SKIP_DB_SETUP" ]; then
  # TODO: write Node code that waits until a database connection succeeds
  ./node_modules/.bin/sequelize db:create || true
  ./node_modules/.bin/sequelize db:migrate
fi
exec "$@"
```

and use that as the ENTRYPOINT of my image.